# Progress indicator when copying local files on MacBook Pro is also visible on Mac Studio

Tags: macos, finder, copy-paste

I am using a MacBook Pro and Mac Studio. Both devices are running macOS 12.5.1 Monterey.

When I am copying files from one location to another on my MacBook Pro (both local to the MacBook Pro) the file copy progress appears on the MacBook Pro as expected, however, the progress also appears on my Mac Studio. I can cancel the progress indicator on the Mac Studio without impacting the copy progress on the MacBook Pro. Also, the copy progress indicator still persists on the MacBook Pro.

I would like to disable this secondary indicator on the Mac Studio, but I'm not sure what mechanism causes this?

I was thinking something to do with [Handoff](https://support.apple.com/HT209455), but again I am unsure. Both are on the same local network.

This is a screen shot of what appears on my Mac Studio. Its the same progress indicator thats on the MacBook Pro.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Are you copying these files to your clipboard, and then pasting them? If so, this is Universal Clipboard

Comment: So if it’s universal clip board why is it displaying the progress bar on the Mac Studio? What is the point beyond displaying progress on a Mac that I am  most likely not even looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Ezekiel is correct in that this is the behavior of universal clip board. In the above scenario, the progress I am seeing is from Universal clip board copying the contents of my MacBook Pro's clip board to my Mac Studio's clip board. In this case, the files are multi gigabytes in size. This has the effect of impacting performance on my Mac Studio while this is copy is in process. My assumption is that is not really an issue for small files. Although I like the utility of universal clip board, I can not tolerate the impact in performance and will most likely disable this functionality on my Mac Studio.